# How to display JSON keys in a table - VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using VueJS to create a front-end:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>My JSON</h1>
    
    <table>
      <tr v-for="b in jsondata['techniques'][0]['program']" :key="b.id">
         <td>{{Object.keys(b)}}</td>
         <!-- <td v-for="check in folder.checks">
         {{check.name}}
        </td> -->
      </tr>
     


    </table>


  </div>
</template>



<script>
import cycleDescriptionData from '@/myjson.json'
export default {
  name: 'myJSON',
  data() {
      return {
          jsondata: cycleDescriptionData,

          userInput: this.jsondata
      };
  },
  

};
</script>
```

The JSON I am trying to display is here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.55f0755dbad64a7b95f1ab0725bd6a49&right=local.kaheka.

My aim is to write every row of a table with the following format:

- Cell 1: Name of key (under object['techniques'][0]['program'], ex: Is
- Cell 2: Value under key "I"
- Cell 3: Value under key "I.1"

So the first row of the table would look like:

Is | 0.000 | -250.000

My question is how do I refer to the key name that belongs in the first column of cells? The current code produces only the first column, where the output looks like this:

[image: Webpage output]

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking a look at  https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table

In your "data" part you can define "fields" (which should have the names of the JSON-Keys).

By creating the b-table :fields="yourFields" :options="yourJSON" it will automatically generate a table.